# different fileds for a model in yii2 rest api

Tags: php, rest, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I created custom actions for rest api in yii2

my codes are:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\web\Response;
use Yii;
class RsController extends ActiveController{

    public $modelClass='app\models\Mymodel';
    /*some another actions*/

    public function actionOne($id){

        return \app\models\Anothermodel::findAll(['my_id'=>$id]);
    }


    public function actionTwo($id){
            return \app\models\Anothermodel::findAll(['my_name'=>'xxxx']);

    }
}
```

I know we can override **fields function** in model to get special fields but
now I wanted to get *different fields* for actionOne and actionTwo (**of a model**)
How can I override fields function in Anothermodel for this purpose?

Comment: Check fields() method: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-arrayabletrait.html#fields()-detail

Comment: I know about fields but I don't know how can I get my special purpose

Comment: What are special conditions that differ output data from actionOne and actionTwo?

Comment: It' related to controllers but my controller names are null when I trying to get them in field function.

Comment: Fields () return different output based on its internal members. I think that you should create different models (inherited from same Base model) for the two different actions. Otherwise you could get return from ActiveRecord find method and then traverse it to fill specific property that you can check inside its fields() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer from [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7098)
I create a component like this

```
<?php

namespace app\components;


class Serializer extends \yii\rest\Serializer {

    public $defaultFields;
    public $defaultExpand;

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->defaultFields = !is_null($this->defaultFields) ? implode(",", $this->defaultFields) : $this->defaultFields;
        $this->defaultExpand = !is_null($this->defaultExpand) ? implode(",", $this->defaultExpand) : $this->defaultExpand;
    }

    protected function getRequestedFields() {
        $fields = is_null($this->request->get($this->fieldsParam)) ? $this->defaultFields : $this->request->get($this->fieldsParam);
        $expand = is_null($this->request->get($this->expandParam)) ? $this->defaultExpand : $this->request->get($this->expandParam);

        return [
            preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $fields, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY),
            preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $expand, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY),
        ];
    }

}
```

and then in my controllers action set my fields
like this.

```
public function actionOne($id){
      $this->serializer['defaultFields'] = ["field1",
        "field2"];
        return new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => \app\models\Anothermodel::find()->where(['my_id'=>$id]),
        ]);
    }


   public function actionTwo($id){
         $this->serializer['defaultFields'] = ["field1",
         "field2","field3"];
        return new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => \app\models\Anothermodel::find()->where(['my_id'=>$id]),
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [events](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-events)

```
public function actionPublic()
{
    \yii\base\Event::on(Thing::class, Thing::EVENT_AFTER_FIND, function ($event) {
        $event->sender->scenario = Thing::SCENARIO_SEARCH_PUBLIC;
    });
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Thing::find(),
    ]);
}


public function actionPrivate()
{
    \yii\base\Event::on(Thing::class, Thing::EVENT_AFTER_FIND, function ($event) {
        $event->sender->scenario = Thing::SCENARIO_SEARCH_PRIVATE;
    });
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Thing::find(),
    ]);
}
```

and inside of ActiveRecord (Thing in my case) check the scenario in fields() method

```
 public function fields()
 {
    $fields = parent::fields();

    if ($this->scenario === self::SCENARIO_SEARCH_PUBLIC) {
        unset($fields['field1'], $fields['field2'], $fields['field3'], $fields['field4']);
    }

    return $fields;
  }
```

check my answer in [gihub](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7098)